# Issue to get data from a collection

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to get data out of a list,but facing some issue while getting the data.

```
List<Field> errorFieldList;
Set<String> formValidationResult = new HashSet<String>();
```

Here the data added to validationResults is like and errorFieldList size is two having Id and type

```
validationResults.put(errorFieldList, formValidationResult);

public ValidationResponseErrorView(
            Map<Object, Set<String>> validationResults, String exceptionMessage) {
    if (validationResults.size() > 0) {
    for (Map.Entry<Object, Set<String>> entrySet : validationResults
                    .entrySet()) {
                Map<String, Object> fieldResultsMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                Object objField = entrySet.getKey();
              if (objField instanceof List) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < ((List<Map<String, Object>>) objField)
                            .size(); i++) {
                        LOGGER.info("in array list----" + objField);
                    }

        }
          }
      }
}
```

I am not sure how to get data out of objField.

Comment: In `(List<Map<String, Object>>) objField`, what do you expect the `Object` to be? And is it possible to specify that type more specifically?

Comment: the object should be of type Field from which i need to get Id and type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is really hard to read and contains a lot of inconsistencies. Especially in your constructor you declare validationResults as

```
Map<Object, Set<String>> validationResults
```

But in your introduction you declare it as

```
List<Field> errorFieldList;
Set<String> formValidationResult = new HashSet<String>();
validationResults.put(errorFieldList, formValidationResult);
```

which means your `Object` is a `List<Field>`. So now you can simply use:

```
objField.get(i);
```

to retrieve the values, where `i` is your index you iterate over. HOWEVER: your code probably won't compile, since you try to cast the `List<Field>` to `List<Map<String, Object>>` in the 2nd `for` loop.

Simply put: rework the code, A `Map` has getter methods for the key and over a `Set` you need to iterate. Check first what data structure you need. Don't nest too deep.

Answer (score 0):

`List< Map< String, Object>> objField` would return you a List which has elements of type `Map<String, Object>`. To get value from this use:

```
    Map<String,Object> mapOut = ((List<Map<String, Object>>) objField).get(i);
    Set<String> keySet = mapOut.keySet();
    Iterator<String> itr = keySet.iterator();
    while(itr.hasNext()){
       Object outObject = mapOut.get(itr.next());
       LOGGER.info("Object"+ outObject);
    }
```